# What to use in place of datasetStrokeWidth for the lastest chart.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, chart.js, html5-canvas

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-o5avid?file=index.ts) is attempting to convert [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ey59atq1/5/) to the latest version of chart.js.

What should we use in place of `datasetStrokeWidth`?  It controls the width of the line.

```
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 10,
    pointDotStrokeWidth: 14,
...
```

I tried `borderWidth` which is in the documentation, however the `ChartConfiguration` type produces a lint error ... and it also does not have any effect ...

Comment: In the stackblitz you defined a `borderWidth`, inside a `dataset`, that works fine and doesn't produce any typescript errors. If you want to set `borderWidth` for all datasets, you have to set it in `options.elements.line`, see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#line-configuration). Here's a [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nks5bj?file=index.ts) of your stackblitz that has both versions, and non-existing options commented out so there's no typescript error.